# ASP.NET MVC 3 Database Context Querying

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have my Database Context:

```
public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public ProductContext() : base ("DefaultConnection") {}

    public DbSet<Product> Products {get;set;}
}
```

and my Repository:

```
public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
    private ProductContext _dbContext = new ProductContext();

    public IQueryable<Product> Products { get { return _dbContext.Products; } }
}
```

when I query my database in the `Edit` `Action`:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
{
    var item = _repository.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(id));

    return View(item);
}
```

I would usually use a `ViewModel` but this is purely to show the scenario.

When I query the database using the `var item` line, does `EntityFramework` change the state of that `item`.

Can I pass around that `item` through a multitude of `Services` in the `Service Layer` and then finally save it using my method:

```
public void SaveEntity<TEntity>(TEntity entityToSave) where TEntity : DbEntity
{
    if (entityToSave.Id.Equals(Guid.Empty))
        _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(entityToSave);
    else
        _dbContext.Entry<TEntity>(entityToSave).State = EntityState.Modified;

    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

It won't throw an exception saying that there is already a `Entity` with the same `Id` as the one you're trying to Save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after trial and error, it seems that this works perfectly fine, and it doesn't bring back any errors. There is one thing to look out for:

This navigation property:

```
public virtual Category Category { get;set; }
public Guid CategoryId { get;set; }
```

That *could* reside in the `Product` model has a little **gotcha**, that is:

When editing or saving a new `Product`, you should **only** set the `CategoryId` and not just the `Category` exclusively because you will get duplicate `Category` entries every time you edit or save if you use the a `Category` that already exist within the database...

I think you should the navigation property solely for your ease, not for use when modifying entities...

Comment: EF will try to insert the category again because it's most likely attached to another instance of your `DbContext`. EF cannot know the category already exsists, so it tries to insert it which causes a duplicate key error. This problem can be solved by using the same instance of the `DbContext` the whole request. Filling in the foreign key field as you mentioned will work just fine though.

Comment: Yeah I think that is the issue, although I am injecting the repository which will use one instance of the `DbContext`, I moving the entities around the place, so it is just easier to use the `Id` fields.

Comment: Make sure you create an instance for the scope of a request.

Comment: Ninject takes care of creating them, I just pull them through the controllers.